# CSS position sticky doesn't work properly when element is inside another

Tags: html, css, header, css-position, sticky

i'm trying to make an element stick to the top, but it doesn't work when it's inside another div. The header div doesn't have any style by itself.

```css
nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

main {
    height: 200vh;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 0%, white 100%);
}

aside {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <aside></aside>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
<main></main>
```

If i apply sticky on the header element it works, but it will also drag the aside element, i want only the nav element to be sticky:

```css
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
}

main {
    height: 200vh;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 0%, white 100%);
}

aside {
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <aside></aside>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
<main></main>
```

This limits a lot what i can do with sticky property if it's intended. The only solution i've found is to remove the header element and keep all elements inside body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `aside` will always have a fixed height use negative  top value and make the parent container sticky:

```css
nav {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -30px;
}

main {
  height: 200vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 0%, white 100%);
}

aside {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <aside></aside>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
<main></main>
```

Comment: this is an possible solution, but only with JS, because the aside isn't always the same height

Answer (score 2):

An element with position:sticky; only becomes fixed with respect to its immediate container I'm afraid, so your best solution without resorting to Javascript would be to move nav inside main.

Comment: that's a big limiter for what we can do with sticky. It's sad that there is no perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

Stiky position acts just inside parent element. So if your element is directly under body, it'll act as you need. You can use javascript for whole page stiky.

```js
window.onload=window.onscroll=window.onresize=function(){
var s=window.scrollY;
var mp=Math.max(0,250-s);
document.getElementById("stiky").style.top = mp+"px";
}
```

```css
#parent{height:3000px;}
#child{height:300px; background:#999}
#stiky{position:fixed; width:100%; height:50px;background:#ff0}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
<div id="stiky"></div>
</div>
</div>
```